# Openshift S2I not overriding scripts in the image after build

Tags: java, docker, openshift, s2i

I am currently using s2i **v1.3.9-dirty** on my MAC to build image of my **Java Application**. I want to override the builder image's scripts. Thus, I have created `.s2i/bin` directory inside my local repository. Inside this directory I have my `run.sh` and `assemble.sh` scripts. When I build the image, it gets created in my local docker desktop but it does not have my version of run and assemble scripts.

```
s2i build . registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/openjdk-11:1.16-2 my-image-name
```

1. Any pointers as to what am I missing?
2. Am I using the right builder image to build my Java application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the scripts don't need to have the extension like `.sh`.
Please get rid of the `.sh` on your script name.

*: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.14/openshift_images/using_images/customizing-s2i-images.html

Comment: Tried that and it still does not work